# Bulk deletion using checkboxes in yii Cgridview

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am new to yii framework.Now i am working on admin side of a project.there is a news taable.It contains all news published by users.I need to delete this news bulkly by using a checkbox.I need code of model controller and view.
I also want code for approving news registered by users.

Thank you

Comment: this is I NEED some code to do something kind of question

Comment: share what you have done so far